How to speedup TreeNode text&color change in Winforms TreeView control, when 380k nodes are loaded and even Begin&EndUpdate ineffective?
I have a TreeView with 380k nodes. I use TreeView.BeginUpdate and TreeView.EndUpdate to populate it, but later I need to modify certain nodes text and color. I tried to do it without Begin&EndUpdate, I tried to do it with Begin&EndUpdate, but it still slow (around 15 seconds to refresh). That way is almost impossible to perform assigned task (I need to modify a lot of nodes one after another).
I read a lot of same questions about TreeView being slow, but it all ends in "use Begin&EndUpdate" or even "switch TreeView.Visible state", but it all doesn't help. What else can be done?
Now I thinking about caching drawn nodes images in a Dictionary<string, Image> text2img, but I don't understand what I need to override to get that image. All I see is being able to change TreeView.DrawMode and subscribing to DrawNode event, but I don't want to draw nodes by myself, I just want to cache them and feed cached image to the code that redraw them so slowly. Node color depends of the node text being changed (changed nodes are green). Maybe, it's wrong way, though.

To have any chance at decent performance you absolutely need "virtualization", meaning you do not create any nodes in the tree until they are actually displayed. This should reduce the number of expensive UI objects from 380k to a few hundred or so. Unfortunately I cannot see anything in the documentation for the winforms treeview about virtualization. So it is possible that it is just not supported.
One option would be to use the WPF treeview that does support virtualization. See How to improve treeview performance and how to use a WPF control into winforms.
Another option is to reconsider the way you present data. Perhaps some kind of search or filter function would be more useful that just presenting it all at once in a tree?
Third option would be to find a third party control, or make your own custom control that includes virtualization. But making your own will likely be difficult and time consuming.

Thank you, but I don't understand something about virtualization. The thing about "do not create any nodes in the tree until they are actually displayed" Currently I represent my data with a lot of classes, each class has a TreeNode as property (and subclasses with another TreeNode properties). Each TreeNode.Tag points to owning class instance. So, first I create all the data, then I put all the nodes into TreeView. So, since nodes are already created, will virtualization work if I put them all into WPF control?

@Kosmo零 The idea with WPF is that you do not typically create your UI objects yourself. You instead create "view model" objects, and templates that describe how these view models are mapped to UI objects. See the link for details.
